# Cardinality of data deriving enum

Tags: haskell

What is the suggested method for getting the cardinality of a data type deriving enum.

```
--given    
data ABC = A | B | C deriving (Enum)
--want 3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Derive `Bounded` as well.

```
data ABC = A | B | C deriving (Enum, Bounded)
```

Then `minBound :: ABC` is `A`, `maxBound :: ABC` is `C`, and `fromEnum (maxBound :: ABC) - fromEnum (minBound :: ABC) + 1` is 3. This is simple and efficient, so it's almost certainly the best choice.

Another option:

Add `{-# language DeriveDataTypeable #-}` to the top of your file and import `Data.Data`. Then derive an instance of `Data` for your type as well. Now `length . dataTypeConstrs . dataTypeOf $ (undefined :: ABC)` is 3. This isn't *too* much more complicated, but it may be a bit slower.

Another option:

Enable `{-# language DeriveGeneric, FlexibleContexts, TypeOperators, KindSignatures, DefaultSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}` and import `GHC.Generics` and `Data.Kind`. Define

```
class ConCount a where
  conCount :: Int
  -- The Generic constraint here isn't strictly necessary,
  -- but omitting it will tend to lead to inscrutable
  -- error messages for missing Generic instances.
  default conCount :: (Generic a, GConCount (Rep a)) => Int
  conCount = gconCount @(Rep a)

class GConCount (f :: Type -> Type) where
  gconCount :: Int

instance GConCount f => GConCount (M1 i c f) where
  gconCount = gconCount @f

instance GConCount U1 where
  gconCount = 1

instance GConCount V1 where
  gconCount = 0

instance GConCount (a :*: b) where
  gconCount = 1

instance (GConCount f, GConCount g) => GConCount (f :+: g) where
  gconCount = gconCount @f + gconCount @g

instance GConCount (K1 i c) where
  gconCount = 1
```

Now you can define

```
data ABC = A | B | C deriving Generic

instance ConCount ABC
```

and use `conCount @ABC` to get the number of constructors in `ABC`. This should be efficient, but it's kind of ridiculously over-complicated.

Comment: Does the first option (using Bounded) work with product types as well?

Comment: @LeifMetcalf, no it won't. So that would be a pretty good reason to use one of the other options.

Comment: It's lame that we can't derive Enum for product types. Maybe `Bounded` ought to have an `Enum` constraint (also shouldn't `Enum` imply `Ord`...?)

Comment: Your last example should do, in instance `:*:`, `gconCOunt = gconCount @a * gconCount @b` right? It seems that's what op wants. Although even then it doesn't actually count inhabitants. I skimmed a paper a while ago that dealt with O(1) enumeration of arbitrary ADTs, with nice properties, in the context of testing. wish I could remember

Comment: @jberryman, I was just counting constructors. If you want to dig deeper, you'd need to specify a bit better what you intended. As for what `Enum` "should" do, I consider the class fundamentally and irreparably broken by virtue of trying to do too many things and therefore ultimately being meaningless.

Comment: You can find generic deriving of `Enum` for more general types than those with only nullary constructors in generic-data: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.3.0.0/docs/Generic-Data.html#v:gtoFiniteEnum

Comment: @jberryman testing-feat? It's not O(1) (how could it) but I believe it's state-of-the-art and there's a paper or two about it.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia that's it, thanks! What I should have said is that `toEnum x` (named `index` in `testing-feat`) is efficient wrt `x` (skimming the paper now you're right it can't be called constant time, but I don't understand the relevant section in isolation). IIUC the point of the work is an efficient `toEnum` where the output in some sense "grows" wrt the index, which are the properties I think `Enum` needs. - "how could it?": hm, I was thinking intuitively of Hilbert curves which I misremembered as having constant time indexing; is that an impossible requirement for a space-filling curve?